# Save R script from RStudio using script and specify the location where file needs to be saved

Tags: r

I have a basically same R script that I need to copy 200 times and just change the random seed at the beginning of each script. In order to automate this, I planned to create a for loop that goes from `i` = 1 to 200 and assigns `i` to the random seed.

However, what I then need is to save each of the files in a separate folder. I have 200 folders named 001, 002, ... 200 and I need each of the script files with the corresponding random seed to be placed in its respective folder.

Please don't suggest workarounds that include somehow not placing these files in folder, because I need them structured this way for sending to the supercomputer to perform some calculations.

I found some answers that use `rstudioapi::saveDocument`, but from what I've seen, it's not possible to specify a path to where to save the file with that function.

Comment: An R script is just a normal text file, so you can do this easily using the base R file and character processing commands.

Comment: Why do you need 200 copies of a script with a hardcoded seed? Rethink your logic there and find a way to run the same script each time with the desired seed instead.

Comment: @MerijnvanTilborg This is not possible because on the supercomputer each job that you want to submit needs to be in a separate folder, set up with the script it needs, in order to submit an array of jobs. Otherwise you would need to submit each of the 200 jobs manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can treat the script just like any other text file, just with the R extention. If I understand your need well I would suggest something like this. Create your script `myscript.R` and add the desired seed value with a placeholder `set.seed(ADDMYSEEDVALUEHERE)`. Then use lapply to change your seed value and write the file in the desired folder.

```
filename <- "myscript.R"

script_as_string <- readChar(filename, file.info(filename)$size)
script_as_string <- str_replace_all(script_as_string, "\r\n", "\n")

lapply(1:200, function(x) {
  my_new_script <- str_replace(script_as_string, "ADDMYSEEDVALUEHERE", x)
  fileConn <- file(paste0(str_pad(x, 3, "left", 0), "/", "mychangedscript.R"))
  writeLines(my_new_script, fileConn)
  close(fileConn)
})
```